# How do I get past "Component not updated" in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, updates, flash

When I visit a site with a Flash video, I get the following notice bar in the latest Chrome Stable release: 
[image]
When I click "Update plugin," I'm taken to [this page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6258784) which doesn't update the plugin but has instructions:

> **Step 2: Update Adobe Flash Player**
>   On your computer, open Chrome.
>   In the address bar at the top, enter chrome://components and press Enter.
>   Under "Adobe Flash Player," click Check for update.
>   Go back to the page with the Flash content.
>   If it doesn't load automatically, at the top left, click Reload.

So I visit "chrome://components/" and I see Adobe Flash Player (there is no "pepper" flash component listed):
[image]
 and I click "Check for Update."  It finds one and seems to download it (New -> Updater started -> Update Found -> Component Downloading):

[image]

But it won't install the update, and just shows:

[image]

Opening the browser with Run As Administrator didn't fix it.  Incognito vs. regular mode, with or without administrator, made no difference.

Deleting the C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\PepperFlash directory (while Chrome was closed) did not fix it.

I even tried going to [Adobe's "Other Versions" flash player page](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/), selecting my OS and for Step 2 selecting a version with "PPAPI" in the name, manually unchecking all the bundleware, clicking to download, saving and running the installer, which reported success, but reopening Chrome and visiting the components list I see the same thing as before with the same version number and the same result of clicking "Check for update."  **How do I update Flash player for Chrome?**